# WillPopScope not working after using Drawer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using drawer of my flutter app .I register first then redirect to Home Page .I have used drawer in my Home Page . I added some some menu on drawer then redirect to some new  activity . I have added WillPopScope in Home page to tigged android back press .But problem is when i clicked back button from  other activity but home activity WillPopScope calling. 
This is home page

```
 return  WillPopScope(

  onWillPop: (){


    exit(0);

  },
  child: MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: StudentDrawer(
            number: widget.number,
          ),

        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.more_vert,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              },
            ),
          ],
          title: Text(
            "Home",
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                letterSpacing: 1.0,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //top(),
              /*SizedBox(
                height: 7,
              ),*/
              bottom()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

This is drawer page

```
return Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[ header(), Expanded(child: list(context))],
  ),
);



  Widget list(BuildContext context) => new ListView(
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
shrinkWrap: true,
children: <Widget>[



  ListTile(
      onTap: (){

        Navigator.pop(context);

        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile(number:widget.number)));
      },
      leading: new Icon(
        Icons.perm_identity,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      title: Text(
        "Profile",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
      ),
    ),
```

And This is my profile activity

```
 return  WillPopScope(
  onWillPop:(){

    print(" It's not calling .....");

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  ,
  child: MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(


        appBar: AppBar(


          leading: InkWell(
              onTap: (){

                Navigator.pop(context);

              },
            child:Icon(Icons.arrow_back,color: Colors.white,),
          ),

          title: Text("Profile"),
        ),
```

Basically everything fine but problem is when i click back button from profile activity its calling onWillPop of Home activity ..